# Red, green, refactor - why refactor?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, refactoring, tdd

I am trying to learn TDD and unit testing concepts and I have seen the mantra: "red, green, refactor." I am curious about why should you refactor your code after the tests pass?

This makes no sense to me, because if the tests pass, then why are you messing with the code? I also see TDD mantras like "only write enough code to make the test pass."

The only reason I could come up with, is if to make the test pass with green, you just sloppily write any old code. You just hack together a solution to get a passing test. Then obviously the code is a mess, so you can clean it up.

EDIT:

I found this link on another stackoverflow post which I think confirms the only reason I came up with, that the original code to 'pass' the test can be very simple, even hardcoded: http://blog.extracheese.org/2009/11/how_i_started_tdd.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Usually the first working version of the code - even if not a mess - still can be improved. So you improve it, making it cleaner, more readable, removing duplication, finding better variable/method names etc. This is refactoring. And since you have the tests, you can refactor safely, because the tests will show if you have inadvertently broken something.

Note that usually you are not writing code from scratch, but modifying/extending existing code to add/change functionality. And the existing code may not be ready to accommodate the new functionality seamlessly. So the first implementation of the new functionality may look awkward or inconvenient, or you may see that it is difficult to extend further. So you improve the design to incorporate all existing functionality in the simplest, cleanest possible way while still passing all the tests.

Your question is a rehash of the age old *"if it works, don't fix it"*. However, as Martin Fowler explains in *Refactoring*, **code can be broken in many different ways**. Even if it passes all the tests, it can be hard to understand, thus hard to extend and maintain. Moreover, if it looks sloppy, future programmers will take even less care to keep it tidy, so it will deteriorate ever quicker, and eventually degrades into a complete unmaintainable mess. To prevent this, we refactor to always keep the code clean and tidy as much as possible. If we (or our predecessors) have already let it become messy, refactoring is a huge effort with no obvious immediate benefit for management and stakeholders; thus they can hardly be convinced to support a large scale refactoring in practice. Therefore we refactor in small, even trivial steps, after every code change.

Comment: @Péter Török, +1 for a elegant and concise answer.

Answer (score 6):

> I have seen the mantra: "red, green, refactor."

it's not a 'mantra', it's a routine.

> I also see TDD mantras like "only write enough code to make the test pass."

That's a guideline.

now your question:

> The only reason I could come up with, is if to make the test pass with green, you just sloppily write any old code. You just hack together a solution to get a passing test. Then obviously the code is a mess, so you can clean it up.

You're almost there.  The key is in the 'Design' part of TDD.  You're not only coding, you're still designing your solution.  That means that the exact API might not be set in stone still, and your tests might not reflect the final design (because it's not done yet).  While coding "only enough to pass the test", you will hit some issues that might change your mind and guide the design.  Only after you have some working code you're able to improve it.

Also, the refactor step involves the whole code, not only what you've just written to pass the last test.  As the coding advances, you have more and more complex interactions between all parts of your code, the best time to refactor it is as soon as it's working.

Precisely because of this very early refactoring step, you shouldn't worry about the quality of the first iteration.  it's just a proof of concept that helps in the design.

Comment: You're a feisty one. I like your style.

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to see how the OP's skepticism isn't justified. TDD's workflow is rooted in the *avoidance* of premature design decisions by imposing a significant cost, if not precluding, 'seat of the pants' coding that could quickly devolve into an ill-advised YAGNI safari.[1]

The mechanism for this deferral of premature design is the 'smallest possible test'/'smallest possible code' workflow that is designed to stave off the temptation to 'fix' a perceived shortcoming or requirement before it would ordinarily need to be addressed or even encountered, i.e, presumably the shortcoming would (ought?) to be addressed in some future test case mapped directly to an acceptance criteria that in turn captures a particular business objective.

Furthermore, tests in TDD are supposed to a) help clarify design requirements, b) surface problems with a design[2], and c) serve as project assets that capture and document the effort applied to a particular story, so substituting a self-directed refactoring effort for a properly composed test not only precludes any insight the test might provide but also denies management and project planners information on the true cost of implementing a particular feature.[3]

Accordingly, I would suggest that a new test case, purpose built for introducing an additional requirement into the design, is the proper way to address any perceived shortcoming beyond a stylistic change to the current code under test, and the 'Refactor' phase, however well-intentioned, flies in the face of this philosophy, and is in fact an invitation to do the very sort of premature, YAGNI design safaris that TDD is supposed to prevent. I believe that Robert Martin's version of the 3 rules is consistent with this interpretation. [4 - A blatant appeal to authority]

---

[1] The previously cited http://blog.extracheese.org/2009/11/how_i_started_tdd.html elegantly demonstrates the value of deferring design decisions until the last possible moment. (Although perhaps the Fibonacci sequence is a somewhat artificial example).

[2] See https://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/permalink/how-a-smell-in-the-tests-points-to-a-risk-in-the-design

[3] Adding a "tech" or "spike" story (smell or not) to the backlog would be the appropriate method for ensuring that formal processes are followed and development effort is documented and justified... and if you can't convince the Product Owner to add it, then you shouldn't be throwing time at it.

[4] http://www.butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd

Answer (score 3):

Because you should never refactor non-working code. If you do, then you won't  know whether the errors were originally in there or due to your refactoring. If they all pass before refactoring, then fail, then you know the change you did broke something.

They don't mean to write any sloppy old code to pass a test. There is a difference between minimal and sloppy. A zen garden is minimal, but not sloppy.

However, the minimal changes you made here and there, might, in retrospect, be better combined into some other procedure that is called by both of them. After getting both tests working separately is the time to refactor. It's easier to refactor than to try and guess an architecture that's going to minimally cover all the test cases.

Answer (score 3):

You make the code behave correctly first, then factor it well. If you do it the other way around you run the risk of making a mess/duplication/code smells while fixing it.

It's usually easier to restructure working code into well factored code than it is to try and design well factored code upfront.

The reason for refactoring working code is for maintenance. You want to remove duplication for reasons such as only having to fix something in one place, and also knowing that when you fix something somewhere you haven't missed the same bug in the similar code elsewhere. You want to rename vars, methods, classes if their meaning has changed from what you originally intended.

Overall, writing working code is non-trivial, and writing well factored code is non-trivial. If you are trying to do both at once you may do neither to your full potential, so giving full attention to one first and then the other is useful.

Answer (score 3):

## Iterative, Evolutionary Refactoring is a good approach, but first...

### Somethings that should not go unsaid...

To build on top of some high-level notes above, you should understand some important concepts from *Complex Systems Theory*. The key concepts to note circumvolve a system's environmental structure, how a systems grows, how it behaves, and how its components interact.

#### *Sensitive Dependence Upon Initial Conditions* (Chaos Theory):

A system's behavior will be amplified toward its most influential tendency -- meaning, if you've many *Broken Windows* which influence how a developer will write the next module or interact with an existing one, then this developer is more likely to break another window. Its even tempting to break a window just because its the only one not broken.

#### Entropy:

There are many, many definitions of *entropy* out there; one that I find becoming to Software Engineering is: *The amount of energy in a system which cannot be used for additional work*. This is why **reusability is crucial**. Entropy is found mostly in terms of duplicate logic and comprehensibility. Furthermore, this ties closely back to the *Butterfly Effect* (Sensitive Dependence Upon Initial Conditions) and Broken Windows -- the more duplicate logic, the more CopyPaste for additional implementations **and** it is more than 1X per implementation to maintain it all.

#### Variable *Amplification and Dampening* (Emergence Theory and Network Theory):

Breaking a bad design is a good implementation, though it seems all hell breaks loose when it happens the first few times. This is why it is sensible to have an **Architecture which can support many adaptations**. As your system heads toward entropy, you need a way for modules to interact with each other correctly -- this is where *Interfaces* come in. If each of your modules cannot interact unless they've agreed to a consistent contract. Without this, you'll see your system immediately start adapting to poor implementations -- and whichever wheel is the squeakiest will get the oil; the other modules will become a headache. So, not only do bad implementations cause more bad implementations, they also create undesirable behavior at the *System's Scale* -- causing your system, at large, to adapt to varying implementations and amplifying entropy at the highest scale. When this happens, all you can do is keep patching and hope that one change will not conflict with these adaptations -- causing emergent, unpredictable bugs.

The key to all this is to envelop your modules into their own, discrete subsystems, and provide a *Defined Architecture* which can allow them to communicate -- such as a *Mediator*. This brings a collection of (*Decoupled*) behavior into a *Bottom-Up System* which can then focus its complexity into a component designed exactly for it.

With this type of architectural approach, you shouldn't have significant pain on the 3rd term of "Red, Green, Refactor". The question is, how can your scrum master measure this in terms of *benefit to the user & stakeholders*?

Answer (score 1):

You should not take the "only write enough code to make the test pass." mantra too literal.
Remember your application isn't ready just because all your tests passes. You clearly would like to refactor your code after tests passes to make sure the code is readable and well architechted. The tests are there to help you refactor so refactoring is a big part of TDD.

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks for taking a look into Test Driven Development.  It is an awesome technique that can be applied to many coding situations that can help you develop some great code while also giving you confidence in what the code can and can't do.

If you look at subtitle on the cover of Martin Fowler's book "Refactoring" it also answers your question - "Improving the Design Of Existing Code"

Refactorings are transformations to your code that should not alter the program's behavior.

By refactoring, you can make the program easier to maintain now, and 6 months from now, and it can also make the code easier for the next developer to understand.